# Caching issues in Gatsby v2 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, websocket, gatsby

I am getting errors running 'gatsby develop' on a [Gatsby v2](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/) site after deleting a few old pages.

> error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open 'D:\dev\my-gatsby-blog\public\static\d\573\path--- 
>   my-blog-post-d-5-f-ef1-Y9bdv2wHaTrcrlb7d2XeeQc6MYw.json'
>
> - websocket-manager.js:21 readCachedResults [my-blog]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/websocket-manager.js:21:24
> - websocket-manager.js:44 getCachedPageData [tutorial-part-four]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/websocket-manager.js:44:13
> - websocket-manager.js:140 Socket.s.on.path [tutorial-part-four]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/websocket-manager.js:140:26
> - socket.js:528 [tutorial-part-four]/[socket.io]/lib/socket.js:528:12
> - next_tick.js:131 _combinedTickCallback internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7
> - next_tick.js:180 process._tickCallback internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9

My particular site is a blog that shows a list of posts on the index. Not sure if its relevant but the deleted pages are Markdown files resolved with the plugin [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the contents of the .cache directory. Using [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) I added a new script to my package.json to simplify the process in the future.

```
"cleancache": "rimraf .cache/*"
```

Comment: I had no issues while using `gatsby develop` but after trying to `gatsby build`, I had this error when navigating to the index. Deleting the `.cache` folder solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Gatsby CLI installed, you can now also run

```
gatsby clean
```

This will get rid of your `.cache` folder as well as `public/` directories.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/#clean